# How to add or create an extra Icon/button in Gmail like "label as:"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api, incoming-mail

When we first login to gmail and select any inbox mail:

1. We can view some icons exactly above the inbox, In that we can also 
   view one icon known as "label as"
2. When we click the "label as" icon we can see a collection of labels
   in the drop down displayed.
3. Now like that I want to create an icon same as "label as" and insert
   an individual label like "general" to tag the inbox mails in bulk.

Can anyone please suggest me an API or an extension add-on which will be helpful to build the required chrome extension functionality using JavaScript?

Comment: This question does not fit Stack Overflow. It's [off-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); as formulated, this is a request for recommendations, and even if you reformulate it, it risks being too broad.